# Create PPM with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm working on a project that requires I use the `*.ppm` image format. I have Adobe Photoshop CC. I can make `*.pbm` (Portable Bitmap), but how do I make a *.ppm with Photoshop?

- [PPM Format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html)

Comment: It is more work, but can you save in another format and convert that to [portable bitmap format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Pixmap) ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Photoshop allows me to save *.pbm (bitmap format), but I very specifically need *.ppm (pixmap format)